# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'href')" error on SharePoint 2010 form load

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, error

When opening a SharePoint 2010 form in modal mode I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'href')

See code below for usage and troubleshooting.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(OnLoad, "sp.js");
  function OnLoad() {

      var id = GetUrlKeyValue("ID", false, location.href); <== Error
      createCookie("Parent", id); // Create cookie

  } // End onload
}); // End document ready
```

I'm not sure what happened yesterday, but this has been working for years in other projects in SP, but for this particular project just popped up this error.

Comment: Which browser & version are you using? Try using `window.location.href`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Ganesh, this worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I have added the same as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.location.href` instead of `location.href` like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(OnLoad, "sp.js");
  function OnLoad() {

      var id = GetUrlKeyValue("ID", false, window.location.href); 
      createCookie("Parent", id); // Create cookie

  } // End onload
}); // End document ready
```